How to play/pause audio if phone is connected to bluetooth via bluetooth headset
I am working on flutter app which has audio player functionality.For handling audio I am using audioplayer package and its working fine .
Now When audio player is running and if mobile connected to bluetooth then user can play or pause audio using connected bluetooth device button or tap gesture.
I spent almost two days in this functionality but not found any proper solution
Do you have any solution for same.
It will great if anyone can help

It's unclear what your question is. As you say, the user can play or pause using their device. What problem do you have?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@RobNapier ,
I want to play / pause audio in my app using connected bluetooth device (Bluetooth headset).

To play/pause in your app, you'll call the play or pause method on your player (I don't know which "audioplayer" package you mean; there are several). If the user wants to control it from the headset, they'll just press the play/pause button the headset. There's nothing your app needs to do here. What problem are you having? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

@RobNapier
No its not working as you said.

In what was is it not working? You need to describe the setup, what you do, what behavior you expect, and what behavior occurs. You need to include the code you've written, and what you expect it to do, and what it does do. If the problem is in the physical controls, you need to explain what kind of bluetooth device you have connected and to what kind of phone. What do you do? What do you believe should happen? What does happen? As written, we cannot help you with this question, but if you edit to include the relevant details of your problem, me may be able to.
